# Is it possible to know how many clients subscribed a "channel" in redis?

Tags: node.js, redis

I didnt find any commands to know how many client subscribed a channel (subscribe) in redis...
Somebody know?

Thanks,

Answer (score 6):

[Publish](http://redis.io/commands/publish)

> **Return value**
>  Integer reply: the number
>   of clients that received the message.

That way when you publish to your channel, you be informed how many users are connected.

---

You could also keep track of this yourself using [incr](http://redis.io/commands/incr) to increment counter when somebody subscribes to that channel and [decr](http://redis.io/commands/decr) on unsubscribe to that channel. That way you can always know how many users are connected to that channel.